# Try to parse an not well formed UTF-8 xml file with PHP

Tags: xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML File, but there is one place where the XML file is not well formed. I have try many many converts and stuff, but nothing helps. As first I have try with simplexml, then I have try with XMLReader, but I become ever the error: "parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x0C 0x41 0x62 0x6F" .

Is there a trick, where I can manipulate the xml content as first, before I put it into simplexml? Or has anyone a better XML parser, who works with not well formed xml strings?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: If it's not well-formed then it's not XML. Start by thinking of it as a non-XML file; that gets you in the right mindset to realise that you need non-XML tools to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used DOmDocument with some success:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadHtml($r);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('mytag') as $t) {...etc..}
```

After you have loaded the doc there are some functions you can call that will try to clean it up, [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument)

Comment: Well I have made an non XML parser with regular expressions and I think this is the only one think that have helped me!